# $\pi = 0$! It can't be!

Tags: proof-verification

Keep in mind: I'm still in high-school so forgive my poor maths. Also remember that I'm in **HIGH-SCHOOL** so nothing to *complex*

I like to mess around with equations and I find it quite fascinating the results I can somehow come up with. Recently, I found [Euler's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) and started to mess around with this. Somehow I can up with the following result: $π = 0.$ I thought to myself, as anyone would, how is this possible?

I then decided to show my proof to my maths teacher and my parents and neither one could show me where I went wrong so I was hoping someone here could.

This is my proof:

$$e^{iπ} + 1 = 0$$
$$e^{iπ} = -1$$
$$e^{2iπ} = 1$$
$$2iπ = \ln(1) = 0$$
$$4\times-1\timesπ = 0$$
$$-4π^2 = 0$$
$$0 = 4π^2$$
$$0 = 2π$$
$$0 = π$$

#### Edit

As I pointed out above, my maths knowledge isn't that advanced, compared to people on this site. Therefore the answer(s) I accept and/or upvote will be based on understandability as well as how well they answer the question.

Comment: Be careful with taking logarithms of complex numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh, my dear, when we consider complex numbers, then it follows that$$\ln(1)=2\pi ik$$and more generally,$$\ln(z)=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{arg}(z)+2\pi ik$$Here is a good link to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function

Comment: Since the exponential is not one-to-one on the complex numbers, it does not have a well-defined inverse.

Comment: A similar proof: $\sin(\pi) = \sin(0)$, therefore $\pi=0$.

Comment: Be very careful inverting multi-valued functions.

Comment: The first line ends with a nice pun ;)

Comment: I was wondering when anyone was going to notice that :)

Comment: Well, do you know [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula)?  It basically goes as follows:$$e^{\varphi i}=\cos(\varphi)+i\sin(\varphi)$$Thus, we have$$e^{2\pi i}=\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi)=1=\cos(0)+i\sin(0)=e^0$$But $2\pi i\ne0$.  We get an equality here due to the trig functions.

Comment: I find the 6 answers to be hilarious.  Sorry for saying so, but I'm still laughing.  I mean, Dah!  How many times does this need to be asked and answered, and none the less, there are fish who bite the bait. Are any of the six fish who bit saying anything that none of the other fish who bit are saying?!

Comment: Reading the title I thought $π=0!=1$ (0 Factorial)

Comment: Hahahaha! That's good, @Jaideep!  Some folks seem to forget that ! is not just punctuation, and especially not so on a math site!

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ and $y$ are real, then $e^x=e^y$ implies $x=y$.

But if $x$ and $y$ are complex, $e^x=e^y$ only implies that
$$\frac{x-y}{2\pi i}\in\Bbb Z$$

Therefore, from $e^{2\pi i}=e^0$ we can't deduce that $2\pi i=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^z = e^w$ does not imply that $z = w$; the exponential function is not one-to-one on ${\mathbb C}$. Instead, it implies that $z - w = 2 \pi i n$ for some $n \in {\mathbb Z}$. So, the fourth equality of your 'proof' does not follow from the third equality.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is simple. Note that if $0=\log(1)=\log(e^{2\pi I})=2\pi i$ than the logarithm is no mapping. Canonically one give a solution to this type of equations by restricting to the main branch of the complex logarithm.

Answer (score -1):

The $log(z)$ or $ln(z)$ is a set not a value!

It denotes all $z' \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{z'} = z$

What you want is the $Log(z)$ with $arg(Log(z)) \in [0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi)$. Depends on how you define it.

As other said already it's a bit more difficult in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score -1):

"2iπ=ln(1)=0"

In complex numbers $\ln$ is not single value but a multi-valued "function".  So $\ln 1$ doesn't just equal $0$.  It equals the entire set of $\{2k\pi i\}$ of which $0$ is the only real value in the set.

This is because $e^{a + bi} = e^a(\cos b + i\sin b)$ and trig functions are periodic so $z= e^{a + bi} = e^{a +bi + i2k\pi}$ is not a 1-1 function any more.  So $\ln z = \{a + i(b + i2k\pi)| k \in \mathbb Z\}$ has multiple values.

So from there we can conclude only that $0 = i 2k\pi$ for some integer value of $k$.  Which it does.  ... id $k = 0$.